Is there a quick grounding disconnect for coax?
I am setting up my shack again after 30 years off the air.
So I have been a ham for a while but my knowledge and experience is thin.
I live on an island in Florida with frequent thunderstorms.
My setup is two antennas.
One fan dipole (inverted V) up in a tree 25' high and a hex beam on a 40' crank up tv tower. Both fed by LMR400 with pl259 connectors.
Is there a type of quick disconnect knife type switch(DPDT) that I can use for each of these on the outside of the shack to switch both conductors of the antennas to ground without adversely affecting the antenna performances?
So I am imagining dpdt knife switches with female pl259 connections?
Is this a bad idea?
Thanks
kc4pco

You should check out this answer to a similar question, "Lightning protection by disconnect". It's not a complete answer to your Q, but is certainly appropriate to be aware of!
